# Update a column when a button is clicked Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, crud

I am doing a project in laravel and i want to change a value of a column from 0 to 1 when a button is clicked.

i am using ajax to do this.

view.blade

```
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="j-approve-user" onclick="approveLogin('{{ route('approve', $user->id) }}')">Approve</button></td>
```

ajax script:

```
let getToken = function() {
return $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
 }

function approveLogin(url){
let data = { '_token': getToken() }

$.ajax({
    'url': url,
    'method': 'POST',
    'data': data,
}).done(function(response) {
    //window.location.reload()
})
}
```

Controller:

```
   public function approve($user_id)
   {
     $user = User::find($user_id);
     $user->update(['loginapproval'=>'1']);
     return "ok"; 
   }
```

However, i am getting a status code of 500 when i click the button.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you checked that the url variable has a value in it?

Comment: Route::post('approve/{user_id}', AdminController@approve')->name('approve');

this is my custom route.. if i only return 'ok'; from teh approve function, i dont get any error and in the console i can get the correct url. but when i am trying to update data, i get 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

500 error is caused because a variety of erros, things you may look it up:

- have you checked your laravel error log? `storage/logs/laravel.log` The answer may be there!
- is your model `loginapproval`attribute fillable, not mass assignment?
- have you check whether the `$user_id` or the mode is null then you're trying to update a null model:

Your code.

```
public function approve($user_id) 
{
$user = User::find($user_id);
    if (!is_null($user)) {
        $user->update(['loginapproval'=>'1']);
         return "ok"; 
    }
}
```